# Highcharts Not displaying function's data values

Tags: javascript, function, highcharts

i Have created a Highchart using the Following Highchart's Demo:

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Now What I did I created my Own function to add dynamic values to the Chart.

I created a function to get the dynamic data from a particular php file whose data changes on every page load event.

I am getting the data values in the `getData` function console.log

Here is the Script That I am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){     
     function getData(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'data.php',
                success: function(data){
                //  var number = document.write(data) ;
                 console.log(data);
                    return data ;

                }
            }) ;
        }
Highcharts.chart('chart', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
            load: function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = getData();
                          console.log(y);
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },

    time: {
        useUTC: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}<br/>{point.y:.2f}'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data:    (function () {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push({
                    x: time + i * 1000,
                    y: getData()
                });
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
});

});
</script>
```

Now as you can see that I have created a getData function and getting the data value in return.

On console log under the getData function, I am getting integer Value in return every one second.

the problem is that under the Highchart's function, I am not able to get the data values using getData function, it's returning undefined in the console .

Highchart's is running but it does not show any data points. it is moving but without showing any data points.

Please correct me in the area , where I am doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ajax calls are run asynchronously so you cant really return data from it.

instead you should render chart inside the ajax success function.

A good example is here already.

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data

Basically 
1. point on load to call a function getData
2. in Getdata call ajax function.
3. in success of ajax render chart with new data.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            events: {
                load: requestData
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150,
            maxZoom: 20 * 1000
        },
        yAxis: {
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            title: {
                text: 'Value',
                margin: 80
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: []
        }]
    });        
});

/**
 * Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout 
 * to request again
 */
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'live-server-data.php',
        success: function(point) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is 
                                                 // longer than 20

            // add the point
            chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);

            // call it again after one second - add this if you want to auto refresh
            // setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    
        },
        cache: false
    });
```

}

Comment: wouldn't it make the chart load every time? I just want to append the data

Comment: this will fire only when highchart loads so technically only once.

Comment: Ok. Let me check. if that works, then it would be awesome.

Comment: The example is working fine on my localhost. But I am not able to create the chart as per my need in requestData function. My Data only contain one value. Like ```[4]``` .  the example data have value in this format ```[1567503090000,3]```

Comment: I am able to display my data on the Chart. But right now I am displaying 1 data points in 1 second. is there any way through which I can show at least 10 points in sec. I tried passing the array of 10 points like ```[1,6,4,6,2,4,8,5,3]```. but the chart is displaying some weird transitions.

Comment: add data to some persistent(global) array and pass it to that chart.